# Mixture of Experts on TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

I'm want to implement a generic module on TensowFlow which receives a list of TensorFlow models (here denoted as experts) and builds from that a Mixture of Experts, as it is depicted in the following figure from http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/C16-1133

[image]

So this model gets an input `x` which is fed into the different experts as well as to the a gating network. The final output corresponds to `ensemble output`, which is given by the sum of the outputs from the different experts multiplied by the corresponding gating function `gm`, which comes from the gating network. All the expert networks are trained in simultaneous.

It's important that this module is suitable for batch training. I was looking for something already implemented and found this https://github.com/AmazaspShumik/Mixture-Models although it's not on TensorFlow.

So right now I am looking for pointers and suggestions regarding what the best approach to build this module would be, namely regarding some already implemented TF layers or wrappers that would be particularly suitable for this application.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can do this in an all-in-one architecture by using a gating placeholder.

Let's start with a simple tensorflow concept code like this then add to it:

```
m = tf.Variable( [width,height] , dtype=tf.float32  ))
b = tf.Variable( [height] , dtype=tf.float32  ))
h = tf.sigmoid( tf.matmul( x,m ) + b )
```

Imagine this is your single "expert" model architecture.  I know it is fairly basic, but it will do for our purposes of illustration.

What we are going to do is store all of the expert systems in the matrix's **m** and **b** and define a gating matrix.

Let's call the gating matrix **g**.  It is going to block specific neural connections.  The neural connections are defined in **m**.  This would be your new configuration

```
g = tf.placeholder( [width,height] , dtype=tf.float32 )
m = tf.Variable( [width,height] , dtype=tf.float32  )
b = tf.Variable( [height] , dtype=tf.float32  )
h = tf.sigmoid( tf.matmul( x, tf.multiply(m,g) ) + b )
```

**g** is a matrix of 1's and 0's.  Insert a 1 for every neural connection you want to keep and a 0 for every one you want to block.  If you have 4 expert systems, then 1/4th of the connections will be 1's and 3/4ths will be 0s.

If you want them all to vote equally, then you'll want to set all values of **g** to 1/4th.