# Much time cost from worker to ps server

Tags: python, tensorflow, timeline

I try to test the distribute speed, with one machine of 4 GPUs.

1. I calculate one batch on each GPU
2. Add the four batch on the worker's cpu
3. Then average the four batch on ps CPU and update the parameters
4. Saved the timeline file

But there are no operations from workers CPU to ps CPU with a long time span in the timeline.

I don`t know where the time gone, because of data transfer?
This is test in only one machine.

The timeline is as follows, and the right up operation is average four data batch and updata parameters, here is the timeline screenshot:

https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/16236576/25800351/87f2acb4-341b-11e7-86a1-bfb888405d72.jpeg

Comment: what if you changed your architecture such that you didn't have to send so much data between GPUs?  Imagine I wanted to add a regularizer such as dropout, like really aggressive, like 0.25.  If each GPU got a unique 0.25 of the network then it is free to train and backprop for many training sessions without having to coordinate data.  Then once every 0.1 epoch or so you could combine all the parameters, reshuffle the 0.25 allocation between GPUs and 0.1 more of your epoch.

Comment: Here is another post about how to split up your problem into a mixture of experts (which is what my previous comment really is)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43845397/mixture-of-experts-on-tensorflow/43882142#43882142

Comment: There is not enough information here for me to understand what is going on. Is the model training at all? Or is it stuck?